# Disparar scripts de python con la consola de Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, cli

Buen día,

Estoy trabajando en en `Python` sobre `Ubuntu`, necesito crear una aplicacion que ejecute diversas acciones mediante comandos de consola comunes sin llamar a la entidad de `python3`.

por ejemplo:

```
user@usuario-de-ubuntu:~$ ejecutaComando --ParametroDeComando
```

Esto desencadenaría la llamada a algún proceso escrito en pyhton.

Alguna sugerencia. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Y por que no otro script en Python? recuerda que en linux, si configuras correctamente el "shebang" y das permiso de ejcución al script, no necesitas ejecutar `python script.py` sino simplemente `script`. Por otro lado tu pregunta entra en el terreno de lo opinable por lo que eventualmente terminará cerrada. Saludos.

Comment: Brayan básicamente son cuatro cosas a tener en cuenta: **1)** Añadir script al $PATH (colocandolo en una carpeta que ya esté en él como bin, mediante link simbólico, añadiendo la ruta del script al $PATH directamente, ...). **2)** Dar permisos de ejecución al script **3)** Añadir shebang adecuado como comenta Patricio (p.e: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`) **4)** Eliminar la extensión del archivo (el .py si lo tiene). Con ello podrás llamar al script desde la terminal sin especificar intérprete ni ruta.

Comment: @FJSevilla debieras poner eso como respuesta (aunque yo me conformaría con ejecutar el script como  `./ejecutaComando` para no tener que meter cosas al path

Comment: @amenadiel he creado una respuesta explicándolo algo más detallado, he intentado que no sea muy larga (temas como los permisos o el PATH dan para escribir mucho) y no se si quedará todo medianamente claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ejecutar un script sin tener que llamar explícitamente al intérprete, ni pasar la ruta del propio script y sin usar la extensión del archivo hay que seguir cuatro pasos en principio:

1. **Eliminar la extensión**: en Linux a diferencia de Windows la extensión no importa absolutamente nada a la hora de definir un archivo como ejecutable o no. Generalmente los ejecutables no llevan extensión por comodidad, por lo que si queremos ejecutar nuestro script sin tener que poner el `.py` , .`py3`, `.pyw`, etc simplemente la eliminamos del nombre del archivo.

   Si queremos mantener la extensión o incluso cambiar el nombre que usaremos en la terminal para llamarlo podemos recurrir a un link simbólico (entre otras muchas opciones):

   ```
   $ ln -s ./foo.py ./foo
   ```
2. **Añadir línea de shebang correcta para enlazar con el intérprete adecuado:** con shebang se conoce al conjunto de dos caracteres **`#!`** inicio de los archivos que son ejecutables interpretados (bash, python, etc). Este par de caracteres va seguido de la ruta absoluta del interprete que ha de ejecutar ese archivo.

   Por ejemplo la línea:

   ```
     #!/usr/local/bin/python
   ```

   indica al SO que se ha de abrir el archivo con el intérprete Python localizaado en `/usr/local/bin`. También podemos enlazar con el intérprete de un entorno virtual si queremos, simplemente hay que buscar la ruta del intérprete adecuada.

   No obstante la forma anterior no es recomendada ya que entre sistemas puede variar la localización del intérprete, por eso se recurre a `env` que se encarga de proveer la ruta adecuada de forma automática según el $PATH:

   - Script compatibles con Python 2 y 3:

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/env python
     ```
   - Script para Python 2:

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/env python2
     ```
   - Script para Python 3:

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/env python3
     ```
3. **Hacer el archivo ejecutable**: Cuando llamamos a un script con `$ python foo.py` estamos en realidad llamando al ejecutable python y pasandole el script a ejecutar. Como el intérprete tiene permisos de ejecución no tenemos problemas. Si queremos poder ejecutar el script por su nombre o con doble click es necesario darle permisos de ejecución. El manejo de permisos es un mundo en si mismo, a modo de ejemplo:

   - Permisos de ejecución para el usuario propietario del fichero:

     ```
     $ chmod u+x ruta/a/mi/script.py
     ```
   - Permisos de ejecución para el usuario propietario y grupo:

     ```
     $ chmod ug+x ruta/a/mi/script.py
     ```
   - Permisos de ejecución para todos los usuarios del sistema:

     ```
     $ chmod a+x ruta/a/mi/script.py
     ```

   Recordad siempre que los permisos han de ser restrictivos, si prevemos que el script solo lo van a usar x usuarios solo dar permisos a esos usuarios.

Con los pasos anteriores ya podemos ejecutar el script simplemente indicando la ruta. Si estamos situados en el directorio del script podemos ejecutarlos con:

```
$ ./foo
```

Por razones de seguridad no se permite usar solo el nombre del archivo, hay que referenciar el fichero que lo contiene (`./`). Igualmente podemos ejecutarlo indicando la ruta absoluta o relativa desde otros directorios, p.e: `$ /home/usurio/scripts/foo`.

4. **Añadir el script a las variables de entorno:** Si queremos ejecutar el script desde cualquier directorio de trabajo sin especificar su ruta (`$ foo arg1 arg2`), como por ejemplo se hace con `django-admin` necesitamos agregar el script al path. Esto ya depende de que queramos hacer con el y tenemos una inmensa variedad de posibilidades, por ejemplo:

   - Podemos meterlo en directorios que ya están en el $PATH como `/bin/` o `/usr/bin/`.
   - Crear un link simbólico al script en una de estas carpetas, p.e: `$ ln -s ./foo /usr/bin/foo`
   - Añadir el directorio del script al $PATH solo para la sesión actual. Cuando se cierre la sesión dejará de tener efecto:

     ```
     $ export PATH=${PATH}:/ruta/absoluta/a/mi/directorio
     ```
   - Añadir el directorio de forma permanente al $PATH: para ello podemos editar el archivo `~/.profile` (o [`~/.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/3757)) añadiendo la línea `export PATH=$PATH:/ruta/a/mi/directorio/`, para que tenga efecto de modo inmediato en la sesión actual hacer `$ source ~/.bashrc`.

   Esto también es un mundo aparte y un tema extenso al igual que el tema de los permisos, las opciones dependen de que queramos hacer, la distro o la shell usada también pueden influir, pero la idea es esta.

Con los cuatro pasos correctamente completados deberemos ser capaces de ejecutar nuestro script en la terminal con solo hacer:

```
$ foo argumento1 argumento2...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu respuesta y un poco de investigación logre dar con el resultado esperado.